# Publishing libraries to Googles or Microsofts CDNs

Tags: javascript, cdn

If I wanted to get a javascript library published to the *ajax* CDNs hosted by Google or Microsoft, what would I have to do?

Are there any formal requirements for this, like number of users etc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they contact you, both CDNs host only the *very* top few libraries or plugins, so unless you have a *huge* user-base, this is extremely unlikely to happen.

Comment: An alternative is to pay for something like S3 at Amazon to host your library.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt there are any formal requirements except that the lib has to be wildly popular, and probably will have to be regarded to be of high quality by the companies running the CDNs.

Google's [Ajax libraries main page](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/ajaxlibs/) has this to say:

> Google works directly with the key stake holders for each library effort and accepts the latest stable versions as they are released. Once we host a release of a given library, we are committed to hosting that release indefinitely.

I'd say if you feel your library is popular and good enough - seeing as Google for example are hosting 12 projects at the moment, yours would have to be in the world wide top twenty by some measure though! -   simply talk to Google and Microsoft and see what they say.

[Here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/announcing-ajax-libraries-api-speed-up-your-ajax-apps-with-googles-infrastructure) is a blog post that could provide you with some contacts to approach. Also, the author seems to be somehow affiliated with Google (he's talking about "we").

The [Google Ajax Library Blog](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com) may also be a good resource.